# mysqlclient installation failed with error code 1

Tags: python, mysql, pip

#### Problem

I am attempting to install mysqlclient via:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

I receive the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_kwgf7vk/mysqlclient/
```

#### Background

**Python version:** 3.6.6

**OS:** Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

**Virtualenv:** I receive the same error both inside and outside of my virtual environment

#### Question

How can I successfully install mysql?

Comment: try to install `mariadb-server` before this and then try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw a similar post somewhere else. The solution was:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

activate the virtual environment and execute command

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I don't know if it's gonna help but i hope it will.

Answer (score 5):

As the official PyPi documentation suggests you need to have the following dependent libraries preinstalled

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev python3-dev
```

after that you could do a `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

for linux mint : python3.7

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev libmysqlclient-dev

$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

and then

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/757